# GCS: SignatureDoesNotMatch Error when I try to do a PUT request to a signed URL using POSTMAN

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, postman, pre-signed-url

I have been searching for a solution for a while now, however I have been unable to find anything to solve my issue. I am a bit new to using signed URLs so forgive me if I am missing something obvious.

I am attempting to upload .tif/.tiff files to a GCS Bucket and am able to successfully sign the URL with the following code:

```
def _Base64Sign(self, plaintext):
"""Signs and returns a base64-encoded SHA256 digest."""
shahash = SHA256.new(plaintext)
signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(self.key)
signature_bytes = signer.sign(shahash)
return base64.b64encode(signature_bytes)

def _MakeSignatureString(self, verb, path, content_md5, content_type):
"""Creates the signature string for signing according to GCS docs."""
signature_string = ('{verb}\n'
                    '{content_md5}\n'
                    '{content_type}\n'
                    '{expiration}\n'
                    '{resource}')
return signature_string.format(verb=verb,
                               content_md5=content_md5,
                               content_type=content_type,
                               expiration=self.expiration,
                               resource=path)

def _MakeUrl(self, verb, path, content_type='', content_md5=''):
"""Forms and returns the full signed URL to access GCS."""
newpath = "/" + path
base_url = '%s%s' % (self.gcs_api_endpoint, newpath)
signature_string = self._MakeSignatureString(verb, newpath, content_md5,
                                             content_type)
logging.info("1. " + signature_string)
signature_signed = self._Base64Sign(signature_string)
logging.info("2. " + signature_signed)
query_params = {'GoogleAccessId': self.client_id_email,
                'Expires': str(self.expiration),
                'Signature': signature_signed}
return base_url, query_params

def Get_Signed_Url(self, fileName, md5):
  """Performs a POST request

  Args:
    filename: The file to upload.
    md5: the md5 hash

  Returns:
    A signed url to upload a file.
  """

  base_url, query_params = self._MakeUrl('PUT', fileName, 'image/tiff', md5)

  url_formatted_sig = urllib.urlencode(query_params)

  signed_url = "{}?{}".format(base_url,url_formatted_sig)

  return signed_url
```

The headers I use to sign are verb, Content-MD5, Content-Type, expiration, and resource.

After receiving the signed URL, I use postman to make a PUT request to the URL and include the headers *Content-MD5* with the corresponding value and *Content-Type* with "image/tiff". However, whenever I try to make this request I receive this error:

[Request Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVGTG.png)

I read a lot about how the StringToSign needs to match the string from my code, however, whenever I log/print the signature_string (before I sign it) in the code I get this (which matches the StringToSign as far as I can tell):

```
2018-07-12 10:53:50.945 CDT
1. PUT
t01JA1Dord60By5+X1RL7g==
image/tiff
1531414430
/mlfc-initial/2018-28/e900a4b3-4f72-40dc-b634-07d437bf6eed/1.tif
```

Ignore the "1. " as I just added it to the front of the logging statement to differentiate it from others.

I have tried encoding the headers and have tried various combinations of them to no success. I am running out of ideas on what else to try next in order to solve this and so all help would be appreciated! Again, apologies if I am missing something simple as I am pretty new to this and please let me know if you need me to add anything else.

Comment: If the problem is not with the StringToSign (which seems to match), it must be elsewhere. Have you compared your signing code with the documentation? How are you getting the key?

Comment: I'd like to read your answer to Nuno Cruces in order to understand better your situation and address the question. 
Did you checked this Documentation in order to sign the URL?
[Creating a signed URL with a program](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program)


Also, you maybe want to take a look here:

[Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

Comment: Thanks for your responses! I pretty much followed most of what was done here (though I don't include the Get, Put, Delete, Process, or Main functions instead only having my Get_Signed_Url function): https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-signedurls-python/blob/master/gcs-signed-url-example.py and so I believe I am getting my key from the PyCrypto module.